# Web Starter Kit - Adding fonts

Tags: javascript, font-face, gulp, web-frameworks

Playing around with Googles Web Starter Kit and I want to include a new font, replacing the use of the packaged 'Roboto'.

Where should I include the '@font-face' for this font 'main.css' replacing the 'Roboto' css? Do I simply have to override any styles that use Roboto in my style sheet(main.css) to use say Open Sans?

Would that mean I'm including 2 fonts? Roboto then Open Sans? Is there a way to stop Roboto being used other than overriding the styles?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter two files to change your fonts.

First you need to update the `main.scss` file located in `app/styles/main.scss`.  You will find a reference to `Roboto Condensed` at line 25 `body`, and the actual font css at line 321 `@font-face`

Lastly, you will need to update the `_utils.scss` located at `app/styles/_utils.scss`.  Update the variable `$fontHighlight` located at line 60 to reference your font.

Comment: But theres numerous other references to the fonts is there not?

Comment: You will need to update/change the `body` tag in main.scss located around line 24, as well as the `_utils.scss $fontHighlight` variable located at line 60.  `_utils.scss` can be found in `app/styles/_utils.scss`.  Just remove the reference to 'Roboto Condensed' with your font of choice.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Surely they should implement an easier way.